# Rails 3.0 - can't load ruby-oci8 with Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile, oci8

Rails n00b here - need some assistance. I am trying to port a Rails3 app from Linux to Windows. My Gemfile looks as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.6'
```

I do not have an Oracle client on this Windows machine, so I will not be able to natively compile a ruby-oci8 gem.

I have commented out the 'ruby-oci8' line in my Gemfile and I installed the gem manually from here: http://rubygems.org/downloads/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60.gem. I have also copied the necessary DLLs into `ruby\bin`.

I have verified that it works:

```
ruby -rubygems -e "require 'oci8'; OCI8.new('user','password','pasdev:2700/gen11dvu').exec('select * from ARCS_USER_LO
GON') do |r| puts r.join(','); end"
```

This returns lots of data from my db, so I know it works.

However, if I try to `require 'oci8'` from a rails console (or from the running app), I get the following:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- oci8
```

I presume this happens b/c Rails only loads the gems specified in the Gemfile, but I cannot figure out how to specify it! I already have the gem I need installed:

```
C:\javadev\ashbtw3>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activerecord (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21, 1.0.0)
rails (3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
ruby-oci8 (1.0.6 x86-mswin32-60)
...etc...
```

Yet if I uncomment this line in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.6'
```

bundler tries to download and compile another 1.0.6, which of course fails. I have also tried all of these variations unsuccessfully:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.6', :platforms => :mingw
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60', :platforms => :mingw32
gem 'ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60'
```

Why is bundler trying to install a gem that I already have? How do I properly specify the version and platform to make Bundler see that this gem is already installed, and just include it in Gemfile.lock? Is there some other solution here that I can use w/o installing an Oracle client?

**EDIT 1**:

As per Kyle's suggestion, I tried the following:

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', :path => 'C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60
```

This made Bundler run successfully!

```
Using ruby-oci8 (1.0.6) from source at C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60
```

However, trying to require 'oci8' from the Rails console now gives me this:

```
C:\javadev\ashbtw3>ruby script\rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> require 'oci8'
LoadError: no such file to load -- oci8lib
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60/lib/oci8.rb:20
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

The file it's missing is in under `ext/oci8` in the installed gem directory, yet it does not see it.

Is there something additional I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying the `:path` ?

```
gem 'ruby-oci8', :path => '/path/to/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60'
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle - that looked like it might work, but I couldn't specify the gem directly. When I tried that it said:

    `The path c:/ruby-oci8-1.0.6-x86-mswin32-60.gem does not exist.`
    
It did get further when I used your idea and pointed the path to the installed gem directory, rather than the gem file itself. I have updated my question with the results of that attempt.

Comment: @ValBlant I'm not sure what else to try except adding a `require => 'oci8'` in the gemfile. This is a complete guess. I don't know if it will work. Good luck!

Comment: No luck. `require => 'oci8'` did nothing.

Comment: Dang. It's getting required but then in one of the oci8 files, the paths appear to be mixed up so it fails to require another file. From your stack trace: `/lib/oci8.rb:20`. Sorry I couldn't help more. Good luck.